# Can only rdp or ping to Windows 7 machine intermittently

Tags: windows, rdp, connection, ping

We have a Windows 7 machine that we can only intermittently rdp into or ping.  We have tried this from several different machines and run into the same issue.

We discovered if you reboot the problem machine and try to ping it or rdp it it works fine.  However, after some period of time it quits working and you can't get to it anymore.

We also discovered you can ping from the problem machine to another machine and once you do that you will again be able to ping or rdp the problem machine again.  However, in a very short timeframe (couple minutes) it once again becomes unreachable.

Any thoughts on what is causing this or what additional info would be helpful for me to provide?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Could it have power saving configured to disable the device after a period of inactivity?

Have you tested moving the computer to a different ethernet wall socket or replacing the patch cables?

Does the event log give any clues?

What about replacing the NIC drivers?

Comment: Check wake on LAN settings?

Comment: There was no info from the event log.  I did find that power saving was on for the network card so I disabled that.  I also updated the NIC driver.  One or both of those changes resolved the problem.  Thanks for your help!